# get keyboard layout of active window (win 10)

Tags: autohotkey, keyboard-layout

I use this script to track the keyboard layout on Win 7, it works ok:

```
getactiveKL() {
    active_hwnd := WinExist("A")
    threadID := dllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "uint", active_hwnd)
    code := dllCall("GetKeyboardLayout", "uint", threadID, "uint") & 0xFFFF
    return code
}
; 1049 - RU (hex: 419)
; 1033 - EN (hex: 409)

loop {
    sleep, 600
    KL := getactiveKL()
    tooltip, %KL%
}
```

But it dooes not work on win 10. Namely it works only once - if I set the layout to RU, and then run this script, it detects correctly, but when I switch the layout - nothing changes.
Do you know how to make it work on windows 10?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in this line:

```
threadID := dllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "uint", active_hwnd)
```

It should be:

```
threadID := dllCall("GetWindowThreadProcessId", "uint", active_hwnd, "uint", 0)
```

There are many examples in the web with different spelling of this dll call, so the latter works on windows 10 correctly.